# Override default Jackson provider in jboss server

Tags: jax-rs, jackson, jboss7.x

I'm trying to customize the behavior for the default Jackson provider.  I wrote the following code and put it in the war package, but it does not work.  I'm using JBoss version 7.1.1.Final.

```
@javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider
@javax.ws.rs.Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
@javax.ws.rs.Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, "text/json"})
public class JacksonConfigurator extends JacksonJsonProvider {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(JacksonConfigurator.class.getName());

    public JacksonConfigurator() {
        super();
        log.info("Configuring JSON data field mapping to C-style");
        ObjectMapper mapper = _mapperConfig.getConfiguredMapper();
        if (mapper == null) {
            mapper = _mapperConfig.getDefaultMapper();
        }
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't you be extending ResteasyJacksonProvider and including the jackson jars in MANIFEST file?
see https://community.jboss.org/message/635233.